# How to pass this snippet to a function

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this snippet of code:

```
$xml->items->item
```

which represents some nodes of an xml tree...I want to be able to pass this representation of the tree to a common function so I can process slightly different xml trees with a common function. Problem is that I'm not sure how to pass it...I've tried passing it as a string and then unserializing it inside the function I'm passing it to but that doesn't work....any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point but "I want to be able to pass this representation of the tree to a common function" - then simply do pass it...

```
<?php
function foo(SimpleXMLElement $r) {
  foreach( $r as $e ) {
    printf('[%s; %s; %s] ', $e->x, $e->y, $e->z);
  }
  echo "\n";
}


$xml = getDoc();
// the <a><b> subtree
foo($xml->b->items->item);
echo "---------------------\n";
// same function for the the <a><c> subtree
foo($xml->c->items->item);

function getDoc() {
  return new SimpleXMLElement( <<< eox
<a>
  <b>
    <items>
      <item><x>10</x><y>11</y><z>12</z></item>
      <item><x>20</x><y>21</y><z>22</z></item>
    </items>
  </b>
  <c>
    <items>
      <item><x>99</x><y>98</y><z>97</z></item>
      <item><x>96</x><y>95</y><z>94</z></item>
    </items>
  </c>
</a>
eox
  );
```

prints

```
[10; 11; 12] [20; 21; 22] 
---------------------
[99; 98; 97] [96; 95; 94]
```

Comment: No you weren't missing anything but I'm sure I tried that and it caused an error the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$xml->items` and the string "item". Then, for each item parse the "item" property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing it as `$xml->items->item->nodeValue`? 
I got this from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php).